# Bessel function and upper bound

Tags: integration, functions, analytic-number-theory, bessel-functions

I'm stuck on this following problem: Let $G$ a function such that $0\leq G(t)\leq 1$, and $G(t)=1$ if  $B^2\leq t\leq 4B^2$, with $\operatorname{supp}G\subset [\frac{1}{4}B^2, 9B^2]$ and $G^{(j)}\ll B^{-2j                    }$ then:

$\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}J_{0}(2\pi\sqrt{st})G(t)dt\ll B^2(1+sB^2)^{-\frac{3}{2}}$

where $J_{0}$ is the bessel function. I'm quite sure that I must use integration by parts to use the condition on $G$ but my attempts have failed miserably. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @JohnM sorry for my delay... the source is:http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa79/aa7935.pdf

Comment: I'll take a close look.  I've been meaning to read that paper anyway!

Comment: There is some inconsistency between the paper and your question.  I'm going to edit your question to make corrections.  If you disagree with my edits, let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By repeated integration by parts, we have
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G(t) \,dt = - \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\pi}\left(\frac{t}{s}\right)^{1/2}J_1(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G'(t) \,dt \\= \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^2} \left(\frac{t}{s}\right)J_2(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G''(t) \,dt = -\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^3} \left(\frac{t}{s}\right)^{3/2} J_3(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G'''(t) \,dt.$$
You could keep going, but this is far enough.  Since the Bessel functions $J_\nu(x)$ are bounded on the positive reals, we have
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G(t) \,dt = -\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\pi^3} \left(\frac{t}{s}\right)^{3/2} J_3(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G'''(t) \,dt = O\left(\frac{1}{Bs^{3/2}}\right).$$
Since also $J_0$ is bounded, we also have
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G(t) \,dt = O(B^2).$$
Put both those bounds together to get
$$\int_0^\infty J_0(2\pi \sqrt{st}) G(t) \,dt = O\left(\frac{B^2}{(1+sB^2)^{3/2}}\right).$$

REMARK: This technique relies heavily on the smoothness of the function $G(t)$.  If we just had a sharp cut-off for $G$, then (for fixed $s$) the best bound we could gotten would have been $O(B^{1/2})$ vs $O(B^{-1})$ with the smoothing.

ADDED LATER (at Bear's request):
All the integration by parts steps are justified by the following identity:

> $$\int x^{n+1} J_n(x) \, dx = x^{n+1} J_{n+1}(x) + c$$ for $n \geq 0$.

Comment: I don't understand what property of Bessel function you are using in your integration by parts. Can you write some dettails? thank you for your answer!

Comment: It's a good question.  I'll add in some details.

Comment: thank you for your patience and your help